# Perform a custom (bulk) action in media view

Tags: attachments, media-library, bulk, media-modal

I wish to figure out how to add a custom action button in the media grid view ( upload.php screen) and how to perform a custom (bulk) action to the selected attachments, as shown in the screenshot below.

I wish to find a way to integrate with the media model instead of force with some external javascript/jquery.

The action will be performed to selected attachments using an ajax call, without  reloading the page, and when it's complete, the media view should be refreshed.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.
Thankyou very much in advance.

[image]